# How to set only one ehcache.xml in a multimodule project?

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache, jcache

I have one "common" project where I want to put the ehcache.xml.
Then, I have a series of spring boot projects, using the EnableCaching annotation in this way:

```
@EnableCaching
public class Project1SpringBoot {
     ....
     ....
```

Inside of the application property I have:

```
spring.cache.jcache.config: classpath:ehcache.xml
```

But I'd like to indicate the "common" project classpath, so I don't have to replicate the ehcache.xml file over n projects.

Is that possible? Or can you suggest me a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are saying should work. If the common project contains the `ehcache.xml` file and the common project is in the classpath or your other projects, then `classpath:ehcache.xml` should work.